# Dart communicate with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, dart, dart-pub

Has anyone made a Google Analytics lib for Dart yet, or do we have to use `jsinterop` to communicate with Google Analytics?

Edit: I know there is a [V3 API](https://github.com/dart-google-apis/dart_analytics_v3_api_client/blob/master/lib/src/browser_client.dart), but is it actually used to trackEvent? Any examples?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [v3 API](https://github.com/dart-google-apis/dart_analytics_v3_api_client) available, as well as a [v2 API](https://github.com/dart-google-apis/dart_analytics_v2_4_api_client). Both are part of the larger [Dart google-api project](https://github.com/dart-google-apis) which are auto-generated.